# Runtime Exception for appended class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For the program file attached, I am facing an issue with appending classes. That line of the code fails

CSS:

```
<a class="btn btn--action btn--block" data-dojo-attach-point="sign_in_button" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick: _onSignInClicked" tabindex="2">Verify</a>
```

my code is therefore:

```
drive.findElement( By.cssSelector(".btn.btn--action.btn--block")).click();
```

But I keep getting this error in console:

```
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[contains(@data-dojo-attach-‌​point,'sign_in_butto‌​n')]}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:371)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:476)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
at WebFlock.main(WebFlock.java:23)
```

CODE:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class WebFlock {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //open flock.co on chrome
        WebDriver drive;
        String url = "https://flock.co/?";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        drive = new ChromeDriver();
        drive.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        //find the email text box, enter email and click submit 
        drive.findElement(By.cssSelector("Input[placeholder ='Enter your work email']")).sendKeys("me@farzanshaikh.com");
        drive.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(8000); //wait for loader to resolve

        drive.findElement( By.cssSelector(".btn.btn--action.btn--block")).click();

    }

}
```

Comment: Simply use driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-dojo-attach-point,'sign_in_button')]")).Click();

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: Error response is not clear from what you have posted; can you update that?

Comment: @kushal. updated the error reponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
drive.switchTo().frame(drive.findElement(By.cssSelector("#dijit__WidgetsInTemplateMixin_0 > iframe")));

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(drive,15);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a.btn")));

        drive.findElement( By.cssSelector("a.btn")).click();
```

**Explanation:**

The element was present on an `<iframe>`; hence in order to get to that element we first need to switch to `iframe` using `.switchTo.frame()` method.